# Спутники естественные и искусственные

Tags: этимология

Есть ли сведения о том, когда впервые было использовано слово `спутник` для обозначения естественных (`Луна - спутник Земли`), либо искусственных спутников (`вывести спутник на орбиту`)?

Разыскивая информацию в интернете я обнаружил многочисленные упоминания цитаты из "Братьев Карамазовых" Достоевского (см. ниже).

Использовал ли Достоевский уже существующее значение слова `спутник` как спутник планеты (луна)? Или он создал совершенно новое значение для слова "спутник", основанное на значении "попутчик" ?

> Что станется в пространстве с топором? Если куда попадет подальше, то примется, я думаю, летать вокруг земли, сам не зная зачем, в виде **спутника**. ...Астрономы вычислят восхождение и захождение топора, Гатцук внесет в календарь, вот и все

[Аналогичный вопрос на грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords/25_114) получил крайне общий ответ, не затрагивающий естественные спутники.

---

Is there any information on the first usage of the word `спутник` for natural (`Луна - спутник Земли`) and/or artificial (`Вывести спутник на орбиту`) satellites?

It's clear that at the moment of [Спутник 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputnik) launch phrase `искусственный спутник Земли` was already in active use.

While researching this topic I've found numerous references to this quote from ["The Brothers Karamazov"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brothers_Karamazov):

> Что станется в пространстве с топором? Если куда попадет подальше, то примется, я думаю, летать вокруг земли, сам не зная зачем, в виде **спутника**. ...Астрономы вычислят восхождение и захождение топора, Гатцук внесет в календарь, вот и все

Did Dostoyevsky use already established meaning of `спутник` as natural satellite (moon)? Or did he originate entirely new meaning (based on `спутник` as fellow traveller)?

[More general question on gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords/25_114) received vague answer:

> В середине XX века, в связи с развитием космонавтики, слово приобрело еще одно значение: космический летательный аппарат, движущийся по орбите вокруг Земли, других планет.

Natural satellites are not covered in this answer.

Comment: Не возражаешь если я переведу вопрос на русский?

Comment: Не успел подтвердить предложенное изменение. Перевод добавил незначительно изменив оформление.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Short English version

**Artificial satellite**: Used by [Tsiolkovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konstantin_Tsiolkovsky) in 1911 "ракета... стала спутником Земли". In 1923 he describes artificial planet: "Проще всего прямо направляться с **искусственного спутника Земли**".

**Natural satellite**: Possibly used around 1670 for translation to Church Slavonic words *satellites* and *comites* that were used in Hevelius's book "Selenography" for Jupiter satellites around 1670. In 1744 Lomonosov uses this word to translate 'satellite' from German: "...можно сие заключить из обращения **около кометы ее спутника**, если бы она хотя одного имела".

#### Искусственный спутник Земли

Сложно сказать, является ли цитата Достоевского первым описанием рукотворного объекта на орбите Земли. Если же говорить о серьезном описании именно технического объекта, то, пожалуй, первенство здесь скорее всего принадлежит [Циолковскому](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%AD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). В 1911 году в своей работе *Исследование мировых пространств реактивными приборами* он описывает воображаемый полет в космосе:

> Теперь мы можем совершенно успокоиться, так как ракета приобрела прочное положение: она стала **спутником Земли**.
> С ракеты виден громадный шар планеты в том или другом фазисе, как Луна.

В своих заметках "Этапы промышленности в эфире или в поясе астероидов" сделанных 7.12.1923 Циолковский пишет:

> Работы на Земле. Образование планеты, движущейся кругом Земли — **искусственный спутник**. Решетчатый куб со множеством изолированных стеклом и металлом ячеек. Отправляется по частям. Там соединяются в одно целое.
> Такая же колония кругом Луны. Спуск и заимствование материала. К жизни приспособят ее позднее. Проще всего прямо направляться с **искусственного спутника Земли**.

Обе цитаты приведены по книге ["Промышленное освоение космоса", 1989](http://ruslit.traumlibrary.net/book/ciolkovskiy-osvoeniekosmosa/ciolkovskiy-osvoeniekosmosa.html).

Но устоявшимся термином "искусственный спутник Земли" стал позже. В декабре 1948 года в СССР стало известно о намерении США создать искусственный спутник Земли, а в 1950 году [начали выполняться исследования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-1) по этой программе и в СССР:

> Теоретическим обоснованием для такого письма была серия научно-исследовательских работ «Исследования по вопросам создания **искусственного спутника Земли**», которая была проведена в 1950—1953 годах в НИИ-4 Министерства обороны под руководством М. К. Тихонравова.

#### Луна как спутник Земли

Для того чтобы назвать Луну спутником Земли, даже в переносном смысле, необходимо знать что:

1. Земля движется в пространстве,
2. Луна, и только Луна движется вокруг Земли.

Мысль о том, что Луна сопровождает Землю в движении в космосе стала общепринятой не так давно. Почти два тысячелетия Земля считалась неподвижным центром Вселенной, а Луна (как и Солнце) входили в число семи планет, вращающихся вокруг Земли. В 1543 году [Николай Коперник](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA,_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9) предположил что в центре Вселенной находится Солнце, но еще 70 лет это считалось скорее удобным математическим приемом.

Но даже когда у системы Коперника появились сторонники, это еще не привело к появлению термина "спутник": вокруг Солнца вращались планеты, а вокруг Земли - Луна (и сейчас мы вполне можем сказать "луны Марса" или "луны Юпитера"). Других подобных примеров известно не было.

Наконец Галилей в 1610 году при помощи изобретенного им телескопа обнаружил четыре небесных тела, обращающихся вокруг Юпитера. В 1611 году Кеплер предложил назвать их satellitem ("сопровождающие лица"), впервые выделив понятие "спутник".

Появление этого термина в русском языке, скорее всего связано с переводом с латыни книги Гевелия "Селенография", написанной в 1647 году. В этой книге, кроме описания Луны также приводились сведения о конструировании телескопов, системе Коперника и были описаны спутники Юпитера.

Эта книга была переведена на церковно-славянский язык в 1670-х годах по указанию царя Алексея Михайловича, при этом переводчикам пришлось изобретать отсутствующие термины (например "трубозрение"). Она не была издана, но хранилась в царской библиотеке, использовалась как учебник по оптике и была известна Петру I.

Какие слова использовались для описания спутников Юпитера неясно, но по сведениям, которые привел Quassnoi, сам Гевелий для описания спутников использовал три слова: circulatores, satellites и comites. Последнее слово происходит от com-, "вместе", and ire, "идти". В других текстах это слово обычно переводится на церковно-славянский как сопутникъ и вполне вероятно что оно использовалось и в переводе "Селенографии".

Что касается опубликованных текстов, использующих слово "спутник", то в 1744 году был опубликован перевод Ломоносовым статьи немецкого астронома, описывающей появление в начале 1744 года кометы. В части, посвященной оценке размера атмосферы кометы Ломоносов пишет:

> К сему определению, кроме показанного обстоятельства равной тягости к Солнцу и комете, требуется еще, чтобы знать пропорцию материи между Солнцем и кометою...
> ...Помянутой пропорции нам знать невозможно, для того что только можно сие заключить из обращения **около кометы ее спутника**, если бы она хотя одного имела.

При переводе на русский язык Ломоносов использовал как можно больше русских слов:

> Л. переводил так, чтобы сделать понятными русскому читателю латинские и немецкие термины. Так, например, термин «hipothesis» (гипотеза) он переводит как «произвольное мнение», «relative Schwere» — «излишняя тяжесть» и т. д.

Кроме того,

> Ломоносов ввёл в обращение десятки научных терминов из области астрономии, многие из которых используются до сих пор, как, например, законы движения планет, земная ось,горизонт, преломление лучей, полнолуние, созвездие, атмосфера и другие.

Так что вполне вероятно, что если даже термин "спутник" не был использован в переводе "Селенографии" или не был принят в русской астрономии (на тот момент преимущественно использовалась латынь), его вполне мог ввести Ломоносов.

Из найденных цитат (в том числе цитата, которую привел Alexander Serebrenik) видно, что сочетание "Луна - спутник Земли" уже как минимум в 1822 году использовалось за пределами астрономии, и следовательно на момент написания "Братьев Карамазовых" (1880) Достоевский уже никак не мог претендовать на изобретение этого термина.

---

**Update** Lomonosov uses this term in 1744 (see below)

Using [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8&year_start=1850&year_end=1870&corpus=12&smoothing=1&share=) I have found in several citations for "спутник земли".
1851 - The magazine ["Сын отечества: историческій и политическій журнал - Книги 1-2" on page 17](http://books.google.com/books?id=INEGAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA4-PA17&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=wKfmUcCGOqmIiAK9jIAw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&f=false):

> "Астрономы, наблюдавшие Луну вскоре по изобретении Зрительных труб, находили гораздо более сходств между Землею и ея спутником, чем новейшие наблюдатели".

1864 - [Настольный словарь для справок по всѣм отраслям знанія: ... - Том 3 - Страница 776](http://books.google.com/books?id=1WQoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA776&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=wafmUa7sAqnWiwLN6oDwCg&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&f=false)

> Гершель тщательными наблюдениями открыл, что У.(Уран) имеет 6 спутников, кот. назв. Георговыми спутниками.

As [The Brothers Karamazov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brothers_Karamazov) were written in 1880 - the term was **not** invented by Dostoyevsky.

---

In fact, first 4 satellites of Jupiter was discovered by Galileo Galilei in 1610 and in 1612 he proved that they are orbiting the planet. This has proved that the Earth is not the only celestial body that can be orbited by other bodies (previously the Earth was considered to be the center of the Universe). So, the concept of satellites was known for 270 years when the book was written.

Still there is a question - when the word спутник was used to describe the satellite?

Looks like we need to find when the Russian astronomers began to write the articles on astronomy. According to [this article](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA) first observatory was established in Russia in 1690. In 1725 the observatory in Petersburg was established and there worked the prominent Russian scientist Lomonosov.

I looked through his works on astronomy and many of them were written in Latin. However I found his russian translation of the German article on observation of the comet in 1744. The russian translation was published in 1744 as well. The article among other things is discussing a possibility of finding the size of the comet's atmosphere. Here is what Lomonosov [writes](http://feb-web.ru/feb/lomonos/texts/lo0/lo4/lo4-007-.htm):

> К сему определению, кроме показанного обстоятельства равной тягости к Солнцу и комете, требуется еще, чтобы знать пропорцию материи между Солнцем и кометою или пропорцию их силы, которою Солнце и комета действуют на тело, в равном расстоянии от них отдаленное. Последнее уже нам известно, а помянутой пропорции нам знать невозможно, для того что только можно сие заключить из **обращения около кометы ее спутника,** если бы она хотя одного имела.
>
> *Описание кометы, явившияся в начале 1744 года, с немецкого языка перевел императорской Академии Наук адъюнкт Михайло Ломоносов.*

It is still not clear if this was the first time when the спутник was used to describe smaller object orbiting the larger one. But Lomonosov invented [many russian terms in astronomy](http://www.msu.ru/lomonosov/science/astronom.html):

> Ломоносов ввёл в обращение десятки научных терминов из области астрономии, многие из которых используются до сих пор, как, например, законы движения планет, земная ось,горизонт, преломление лучей, полнолуние, созвездие, атмосфера и другие.

Also, the translation of the article by Lomonosov used many russian words to make the article more understandible to [russian reader](http://feb-web.ru/feb/lomonos/kes-abc/kes/kes-1261.htm):

> Л. переводил так, чтобы сделать понятными русскому читателю латинские и немецкие термины. Так, например, термин «hipothesis» (гипотеза) он переводит как «произвольное мнение», «relative Schwere» — «излишняя тяжесть» и т. д.

So, if the term was not used before, Lomonosov could propose it first.

---

**Update** There is a chance that the term спутник was coined around 1670. According to the book "П. Г. Куликовский. М. В. Ломоносов астроном и астрофизик", by request of the [Tzar Alexey Mikhailovich](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) in 70-es the book Selenographia (1647) by [Johannes Hevelius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Hevelius) was translated into Russian (to be precise - into Church Slavonic). Though it was not published (it was stored in Tzar's library) it was known to Peter I.

> В "Селенографии" была также изложена система Коперника, приведены числовые данные о размерах Солнечной системы и об обращении планет (с точностью до минут времени!), **описаны спутники Юпитера**.

So, it was the first manuscript written in Russian that mentioned the existence of Jupiter satellites, though I am not certain what word was used to describe them. For example the book title was translated as:

> Иоганна Гевелия Селенография еже есть Луны описание и прилежное крапин ее и подвижений различных и иных всех изменений и изображений, зрительного сосуда помощью испытанных,
> определение. В нем же зде иных многих планет природных зрак и многая блюдения, наипаче же крапин солнечных и поветовых трубозрением изобретенных и таблиями вельми прилежно на меди изваянными во увидение полагаются.

Comment: +1 Great findings. I'll wait a couple of days for other proposals on exact origin before accepting your answer. BTW, it was Kepler who [introduced](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/satellite#wordorgtop) `satellitem` (most probable origin for `спутник`) for natural satellites in 1611. Galileo called them [Sidera Medicæa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmica_Sidera#Name).

Comment: @defaultlocale Yes, I also found that information. As for Искусственный спутник Земли - this term was proposed by Королев.

Comment: From the article you [referenced](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/satellite#wordorgtop): Lat. "satellitem" - attendant (synonyms - escort, companion, comrade; follower, retainer, servant). It looks reasonable to translate it as спутник. Let's wait for @YellowSky :)

Comment: @Artemix: Hevelius used three words for the moons of Jupiter: *circulatores*, *satellites* and *comites*. The latter originates from *com-*, "with", and *ire*, "go". In other texts, it was consistently translated into CS as *сопутникъ* and it's plausible that the CS word is a calque of the Latin one. So most probably Hevelius' CS translation did use that word as well.

Answer (score 3):

Ещё более ранний пример:

> Уже большая половина солнца была закрыта спутником земли, и затмение
>   стояло с лишком полтора часа, как никто еще в монастыре не знал об
>   этом. [О. И. Сенковский. Воспоминания о Сирии (1822)]

Comment: Lomonosov uses this term in 1744 (see my answer)